# Getting "ORA-04030: out of process memory" on medium insert with large pga and sga

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, memory, errors

Running on Oracle 12.1.0.2 AIX Power9 *(yes, I know it's 2021, but that's the customer I've got)*

Executing a plsql block that includes 1000 inserts as plain text and commit in the end.

```
begin
   insert into tab1 values (1);
   insert into tab1 values (2);
   ...-- 998 more inserts
   commit;
end;
```

It fails consistently on `ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 20504 bytes (callheap, KTI call freeable small pool)`

The same plsql block runs successfully on hundreds of other databases, including this very version and OS.

The database was rebooted, no sessions except of mine.

The memory parameters are:

```
*.db_16k_cache_size=0
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_cache_size=30g
*.java_pool_size=200m
*.large_pool_size=1g
*.lock_sga=TRUE
*.pga_aggregate_target=10g
*.shared_pool_size=8g
```

I have tried to use internal parameters - no luck, same error

```
*._use_realfree_heap=TRUE
*._realfree_heap_pagesize = 262144
```

Changed `_use_realfree_heap=FALSE` - same error.

The trace file generated claims that the process consumes 95MB only.
[image: trace file memory usage]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Sounds to me like you're flailing around trying any and all "black magic" solution (undocumented parameter changes) that you've either heard about or that came up on Google searches (been there, done that! :-) ). To me, the fact that your query appears **extremely** simple and not very resource heavy (**at all**) suggests to me that there is something fundamentally wrong with your system somewhere. Can you run other queries? SELECTs? UPDATEs? Different INSERTs? What is the `CREATE TABLE...` statement for that table?

Comment: This server is a new ona and it was created just for this database. So, yes, there might be something fundamentally wrong with my system somewhere, since none ever worked with it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, my fellow DBA has found the solution:

**decrease** the pga_aggregate_target from 10GB to 5GB

I guess there are some OS problems on that server that prevent Oracle to allocate 10GB for pga.

Answer (score 2):

> "AIX Power9 *(yes, I know it's 2021 ...*"

That alone deserves an upvote. I truly loathe this platform.

Hitting that error with such low amount of allocated memory is rather an OS configuration issue and not a database configuration issue.

Check the limits configured and change them if needed:

[Configuring Shell Limits and System Configuration Parameters for AIX](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AXDBI/app_manual.htm#CIHDEEGA)